# how to search through an array using specific parameters

Tags: java

```java
package Part01;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MP3Player implements iPlayer {
    private ArrayList<Tune> soundData;
    
    
    public MP3Player() {
        soundData =  new ArrayList<Tune>();
        
    }


    public boolean addTune(String title, String artist, int duration, Genre gen) {
        return true;
    }

    public String[] getTuneInfo() {
        return null;
    
    }

    public String[] getTuneInfo(Genre gen) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

how can i return an array for Tune objects for a specific genre specified by the String parameter.

Comment: `Arrays.binarySearch​(T[] a,int fromIndex,int toIndex,T key,Comparator<? super T> c)` Basically use a comparator. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T%5B%5D,int,int,T,java.util.Comparator)

Comment: You will want to use the Java Stream API for this: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html

Comment: What have you done to make this work? It sounds like you are trying to have others solve your homework.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a list of tune objects, the first thing you need to do is to change the method's return type to

```
List<Tune>
```

Then, inside the function, an easy solution, instead of going through the stream API which requires some time to understand, you could write code like:

```
public List<Tune> getTuneInfo(Genre gen){ 
   List<Tune> aux = new ArrayList<>(); 
   for (Tune t : soundData)
      if (t.getGenre().equals(gen))
          aux.add(t); 

   return aux; 
}
```

Note that maybe you need to write a equals implementation for the Genre object, which I assume is defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Streams API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) is useful here as the resulting code is more expressive then the use of for loops. You will want to make sure you override `.equals()` on your Tune class if comparison by identity does not work for your application and you need to compare by properties instead (the same problem would exist with for loops).

```
public List<Tune> getTuneInfo(Genre gen) {
   return soundData.stream()
     .filter(tune -> tune.getGenre().equals(gen))
     .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
}
```

If you don't want the user of the result to modify the Tune objects returned then you can add a `map()` operation that makes a copy of them to be returned.